# Accessing specific dimensions in GA4 (Google Analytics 4) with access to the Views data model

Tags: google-analytics, salesforce, analytics

How does one access specific dimensions in GA4 when you've got access to the data model Views.

I'm connecting to GA4 through the Salesforce CRM Analytics platform and it only has access to the Views table(?). Is it possible to get to the dimensions I'm looking for in the Query Explorer?

I can query exactly what I'm looking for using [the GA4 Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/)

pulling:
-metrics
--purchaseRevenue
-dimensions
--campaignName
--sessionCampaignName
--firstUserCampaignName

which produces a simple JSON but that doesn't expose what objects the dimensions come from in the [data model](https://cdn.cdata.com/help/DAH/jdbc/pg_GoogleAnalytics4allviews.htm).